# Building an application that lets us stamp shapes onto svg

Tags: svg, onclicklistener, elm

I wrote [this code](https://github.com/luismackmack/example_svg_elm), it is about svg. I would like know how can I do that each element printed in the view does some event when de mouse is over it for example, or onClick, etc.

I am using Elm 0.18, elm-lang/svg/2.0.0

```js
module Stamps exposing (..)

import Element exposing (..)
import Html exposing (..)
import Mouse
import Svg exposing (..)
import Svg.Attributes exposing (..)
import VirtualDom


type alias Position =
    ( Int, Int )


type alias Model =
    { clicks : List Position
    }


type Msg
    = AddClick Position


model : Model
model =
    { clicks = clicks
    }


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        AddClick pos ->
            { model | clicks = pos :: model.clicks } ! []



-- drawStamp takes a position and return a graphics svg


drawStamp : ( Int, Int ) -> Svg msg
drawStamp ( x, y ) =
    let
        string_x =
            toString (x)

        string_y =
            toString (y)
    in
        Svg.circle
            [ fill "#60B5CC", fillOpacity "0.5", cx string_x, cy string_y, r "10" ]
            []


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    let
        group =
            List.map drawStamp model.clicks
    in
        -- Now make a collage containing the group
        svg
            [ Svg.Attributes.width "300", Svg.Attributes.height "300", viewBox "0 0 300 300" ]
            group


clicks : List ( Int, Int )
clicks =
    -- We'll just init positions
    []


main : Program Never Model Msg
main =
    Html.program
        { init = ( model, Cmd.none )
        , update = update
        , view = view
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        }


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Mouse.clicks (\{ x, y } -> AddClick ( x, y ))
```

Answer (score 1):

The package `elm-lang/svg` you're using has its [events](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/svg/2.0.0/Svg-Events). If you import them you can use them in each svg attributes list. Here is your example with `Debug.log` output of circle position you mouseover.

```elm
module Stamps exposing (..)

import Element exposing (..)
import Html exposing (..)
import Mouse
import Svg exposing (..)
import Svg.Attributes exposing (..)
import Svg.Events exposing (onMouseOver)
import VirtualDom

type alias Position =
    ( Int, Int )

type alias Model =
    { clicks : List Position
    , mouseOver : Position
    }

type Msg
    = AddClick Position
    | MouseOver Position

model : Model
model =
    { clicks = clicks
    , mouseOver = (0, 0)
    }

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        AddClick pos ->
            { model | clicks = pos :: model.clicks } ! []
        MouseOver pos ->
            { model | mouseOver = Debug.log "Mouse over position" pos } ! []

-- drawStamp takes a position and return a graphics svg

drawStamp : ( Int, Int ) -> Svg Msg
drawStamp ( x, y ) =
    let
        string_x =
            toString (x)

        string_y =
            toString (y)
    in
        Svg.circle
            [ fill "#60B5CC", fillOpacity "0.5", cx string_x, cy string_y, r "10", onMouseOver <| MouseOver (x, y) ]
            []

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    let
        group =
            List.map drawStamp model.clicks
    in
        -- Now make a collage containing the group
        svg
            [ Svg.Attributes.width "300", Svg.Attributes.height "300", viewBox "0 0 300 300" ]
            group

clicks : List ( Int, Int )
clicks =
    -- We'll just init positions
    []

main : Program Never Model Msg
main =
    Html.program
        { init = ( model, Cmd.none )
        , update = update
        , view = view
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        }

subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Mouse.clicks (\{ x, y } -> AddClick ( x, y ))
```

Comment: Thank u for your attention

Answer (score 0):

I has solved this way

```js
...

type Msg
    = AddClick Position
    | EventClick


model : Model
model =
    { clicks = clicks
    }


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        EventClick ->
            let
                _ =
                    Debug.log "msg1" "EventClick in Action"
            in
                ( model, Cmd.none )

        AddClick pos ->
            { model | clicks = pos :: model.clicks } ! []



-- drawStamp takes a position and return a graphics svg


drawStamp : ( Int, Int ) -> Svg Msg
drawStamp ( x, y ) =
    let
        string_x =
            toString (x)

        string_y =
            toString (y)
    in
        Svg.circle
            [ fill "#60B5CC", fillOpacity "0.5", cx string_x, cy string_y, r "30", onClick EventClick ]
            []
...
```